# Output from a PHP web-page stops in its tra

Tags: php, debugging

After a recent but as-yet unknown change, the output of a PHP web-page now *stops* at a particular source-line (which is immediately prior to a `<?php } else {` construct).  Nothing from that precise point ever arrives at the user's browser.  I see no `exit` statements in the code, and there are no log-messages of any kind.  (About 183K of output had been transferred – nothing remarkable there.)

How might I begin to tackle this problem?

One clue that I ''did'' notice is that, when I started regressing this source-code backward to earlier versions that were known-good, the problem persisted!  This strongly suggests to me that the problem is actually in an included file.  *(This eleven-year old program is truly ghastly, except that it works and make lots of money.)*  How might I begin sleuthing-out where the problem actually is?

Comment: I did have a similar issue I wasn't able to solve for days. Only occured on a single server. Ultimately it seemed that it was due to too many php open and close tags. Reducing the source code in the view file (in my case) resolved the issue. As you also experience, I wasn't actually able to find any log or any error on this.

Comment: I only wish there was a way I could he

Comment: My first suggestion would be to make sure error reporting gets enabled and stays enabled. You said there are no log messages, but if your script dies halfway through, it seems like there really should be. I would search the code for places where error reporting may be getting turned off.